# How to submit nested attributes via parent _form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Upon clicking `submit` only the `Duel` attributes are passing - not `Dueler`.

**duels_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @duel = Duel.new
    @user = User.find(params[:challenge_daddy]) # This pulls in the ID for Challenged User

    # Current User
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
    @current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at)

    # Challenged User
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: @user.id, user_name: @user.name, user_last_name: @user.last_name)
    @challenged_user_challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)

    respond_with(@duel)
  end
```

I think I have to submerge the dueler info (i.e. `full_name` and `collection_select`) within something like `<%= simple_form_for(@dueler) do |f| %>`, but then I don't want two separate `submit` buttons. When the user clicks submit the `dueler` and `duel` information should both submit since they go hand-in-hand. Right now only the `duel` information submits and the `dueler`s are never created.

**duels/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= current_user.full_name %> WILL <%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @current_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>
  <%= @user.full_name %> WILL <%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenged_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>

  THE LOSER WILL <%= f.text_field :consequence %>.
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### UPDATE

Originally I had this in the _form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
  <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
<% end %>
```

But I took it out because the `duels_controller` `new` logic wasn't passing into it so I moved the code directly into the _form, but now I'm not sure what should take the place of `<%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>`

```
class Dueler < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :duel
end

class Duel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :challenge
  has_many :duelers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :duelers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
end

class DuelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_duel, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :duel_request]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @duels = Duel.joins(:duelers).all
    redirect_to duel(@duel)
  end

  def duel_request
    @dueler = @duel.duelers.where(user_id: current_user)
  end   

  def show
    @dueler = Dueler.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def user_challenges
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  end

  def new
    @duel = Duel.new
    @user = User.find(params[:challenge_daddy])
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
    @current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at)
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: @user.id, user_name: @user.name, user_last_name: @user.last_name)
    @challenged_user_challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @duel = Duel.new(duel_params)
    @duel.save
    #redirect_to duel_request_url(@duel)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def update
    @duel.update(duel_params[:duelers_attributes])
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def destroy
    @duel.destroy
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  private
    def set_duel
      @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
    end

    def duel_params
      params.require(:duel).permit(:consequence, :reward, duelers_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :challenge_id, :accept])
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried "Nested Forms". If not check  https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: can you post your dueler and duel models, as well as the rest of your duels controller.  the code you posted isn't enough to see what's going on.  nested attributes/nested forms have more moving parts

Comment: Okay @ren I added code :)

Comment: just a hunch but how are you associating dueler with @duel in your form?  they have a one-to-many association so the dueler object should have a `duel_id`.  this could be done with `@duel.duelers.build` in the `new` action..

Comment: Yea @Ren `dueler` does have a `duel_id`. I added `@duel.duelers.build` to `new`. Then clicked `submit`, but still no dueler was created upon creation of duel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `has_many` and `belongs_to` with `accepts_nested_attributes` you will need to use `inverse_of` to prevent Rails from attempting to lookup records (which of course don't exist because you haven't yet created them)

Change your Duel model has_many declaration to:

```
  has_many :duelers, inverse_of: :duel
```

For further details on this and an example of a nested form with has_many relationship using Simple Forms check out:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: Thanks for trying! I think the root of the problem is the form. When I click submit it only submits for `duel`. Do you know how I can pass the content  via maybe nesting another form in that form?

Comment: The response i gave is still valid. If you do have a working form you still won't be able to save without doing the inverse_of. I wasn't sure what your form looked like as you didn't have the partial in your question. Could you add that to the question please and I will have a look.

Comment: I don't have a partial good sir. That's my main problem sorry that wasnt clear in the question. I don't know how to write that partial.

Comment: Just to be clear -   `<%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>`, you don't have a _dueler_fields.html.erb at all?

Comment: Check out https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through. It contains an example view for the nested form using Simple Forms